# Remove empty data from a JSON Object

Tags: json, typescript

I have a Typescript class in which I collect a JSON Object with some empty parameters, what I want is to filter that object to obtain another Object but without the empty data of the first one.

This is my JSON object:

```
{ Country: 'Colombia',
  Ser: 'ok',
  Ins: '',
  BBDD: 'ok',
  Mid: '',
  Ata: '',
  'Branch Ser': 'ok',
  Service: '' }
```

This is what I want to achieve:

```
{ Country: 'Colombia',
      Ser: 'ok',
      BBDD: 'ok',
      'Branch Ser': 'ok' }
```

Comment: Have you tried not using the class to collect the object? just use "any" type. I assume you are only receiving the populated entries from the original object in the first place so why add the object to the class and get empty properties?

Comment: @CyberDev I don't want to get the empty properties, I want to remove the empty properties to get the second object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const allData = {
  Country: 'Colombia',
  Ser: 'ok',
  Ins: '',
  BBDD: 'ok',
  Mid: '',
  Ata: '',
  'Branch Ser': 'ok',
  Service: ''
};

const filteredData = Object.entries(allData).reduce((x, [k, v]) => {
  if (v) { // not ( null, undefined, empty string)
    x[k] = v;
  }
  return x;
}, {} as any);

console.log(filteredData);
```

You can use `Object.entries` function to list object as key value pairs and then use the `Array.reduce` to filter out the falsy values.

Comment: This shows me the following error in `x[k]`: ```The element has type "any" implicitly because the expression of type "string" cannot be used to index the type "{}".
   No index signature was found with a parameter of type "string" in type "{}".```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const allData = {
  Country: 'Colombia',
  Ser: 'ok',
  Ins: '',
  BBDD: 'ok',
  Mid: '',
  Ata: '',
  'Branch Ser': 'ok',
  Service: ''
};

const filteredData = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(allData).filter(([_, value]) => value));


console.log(filteredData);
```

Above is a simple one-line solution to do it. Using JS' [Object.fromEntries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) really helps.